# Magento 1.9 PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getFrontNameByRoute() on boolean line 382

Tags: magento-1.9, nginx, php-5.6, php-fpm

Sometimes I get this error in my Magento 1.9 but I cannot debug the reason. It happens quite rarely but I would like to find out why. Can you help me debug?

this is my code at around  like 382. File is Mage/Core/Model/Url/Rewrite/Request.php

```
protected function _getRouterByRoute($routeName)
    {
        // empty route supplied - return base url
        if (empty($routeName)) {
            $router = $this->_getRouter('standard');
        } elseif ($this->_getRouter('admin')->getFrontNameByRoute($routeName)) {
            // try standard router url assembly - above is line 382
            $router = $this->_getRouter('admin');
        } elseif ($this->_getRouter('standard')->getFrontNameByRoute($routeName)) {
            // try standard router url assembly
            $router = $this->_getRouter('standard');
        } else {
            // try custom router url assembly
            $router = $this->_getRouter($routeName);
            if (!$router) {
                // get default router url
                $router = $this->_getRouter('default');
            }
        }
        return $router;
    }
```

What about this code, should it avoid generating a PHP Fatal error?

```
if (empty($routeName)) {
    $router = $this->_getRouter('standard');
} elseif ($adminRouter = $this->_getRouter('admin')) {
    $adminFrontName = $adminRouter->getFrontNameByRoute($routeName);
    if (is_string($adminFrontName)) {
        $router = $adminRouter;
    } else {
        //  $adminFrontName is a boolean?
    }
}
```